# How to translate "main"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective, word-choice

I am looking for a Latin adjective — or several adjectives if no single one is enough — meaning "main".
I might want to talk about a main building or the main idea of a theory.
The only suitable adjective I know is *principalis*, but is this the best choice and are there other words I should know?
Fore example, *aedificium principale* sounds fine, but I don't know if this is the best choice.
In some languages one can use the noun "head" in this meaning (German "haupt-" and Finnish "pää-", for example), but the corresponding Latin adjective *capitalis* seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't much beyond the words you have indicated, which are already satisfactory, but I assume that you would like a bit more scope for expression, for which both *superus* in its degrees of comparison and *caput* can be useful in working round the problem.

1. The simple adjective *superus* indicates a higher position, as in *pars supera*, 'the part above', or 'the upper part' etc, while Its comparative *superior* can be used to describe condition, number or quantity. By manipulating the context, either can suggest 'main'.
2. The superlative, formally *superrimus*, is more familiar in its shortened form *summus* (and *superus* is also found, though I believe its use is more often poetical). It expresses the highest, most exalted, topmost and so on and it is also better translated in some circumstances as 'main'. In particular, *summus* is used substantively as in *summa* (sc. res) the main point, and adjectivally as in *summa rerum* (though the usage may exist, I have never seen *summarum rerum*). *Salus respublicae summa lex* is a common legal dictum, 'the main law is [that of] the safety of the state'.
3. As for *caput*, Livy, for example, has *capita coniurationis* for 'the main conspirators'  [Liv. 10, 1 *capitaque coniurationis eius quaestione ab consulibus ex senatus consulto habita virgis caesi ac securi percussi*]. The phrase *caput itinerum* occurs in various itineraries, for instance *Augusta Vindelicorum veluti Caput itinerum in itinerario Antonini.* *Caput litterarum* and *caput rerum* also occur. The usage is easily adapted to other situations, e.g. *caput aedificiorum*, the main building.

Answer (score 4):

There were some good suggestions in the comments, and I want to record them here to give them more visibility.
If anyone wants to elaborate on any of them, feel free to add a separate answer.
I made this answer community wiki so that I get no reputation (I didn't do anything!) and anyone can edit easily.

Here are some possible translations for "main":

- *principalis*
- *primus*
- *princeps*
- *praecipuus*
- the prefix *archi-*
- *maior*